# Layout issue with my android preferences

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Started messing around with Android recently and wanted to create a preference screen within my app. For this I am using the [android UI settings guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html). However when I get the `SettingsFragment` to load on my screen, the first `PreferenceCategory` is behind my action bar. I can't see to figure out what is causing this. I know this only because I hid the action bar and saw it behind. If I can get this shifted down a little, I would be happy with that. But don't understand much on how these preferences are formatted.

Here is what I have done to create this. Do I require a layout for this fragment? If so how do I add that?

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

        ((SettingsActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar().show();
        ((SettingsActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar().setTitle(" Settings");

        //Loading the preference XML for the user profile settings
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    }

}
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    //@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        //setContentView(R.layout.fragment_settings);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();

    }
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="PROFILE SETTINGS"
        android:key="pref_user_settings">
        <Preference
            android:key="perf_username"
            android:summary="geddon"
            android:title="@string/perf_username">
        </Preference>
        <Preference
            android:key="perf_gender"
            android:summary="Female"
            android:title="Gender">
        </Preference>
        <Preference
            android:key="perf_email"
            android:summary="geddon@gmail.com"
            android:title="Email">
        </Preference>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/perf_user_settings"
        android:key="pref_key_preferences_settings">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="perf_country"
            android:title="Country"
            android:dialogTitle="Country"
            android:defaultValue="USA">
        </ListPreference>

        <Preference
            android:key="perf_password"
            android:summary="password"
            android:title="Change Password">
        </Preference>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**ScreenShot**
[image]

Comment: what does the activity layout look like? does it work if you show the action bar in the activity instead of in the fragment

Comment: Updated with a screen shot and you can see the android:title="PROFILE SETTINGS" category is hidden.

Comment: have you tried setting the action bar to be shown in the activity before making the fragment transaction

Comment: Yes, I have tried that also. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

try setting a layout in the activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
```

where activity_layout is just an empty framelayout or something. then show the action bar in the activity. and i think that will do it.

Comment: I think I did try that, if you look at my SettingsActivity I have that commented out using a fragment_settings.xml layoyt. If i do that, I still need to use the getFragmentManager(). right? Regardless, I was able to get the layout displayed on top of the preferences as a test and noticed that was also shifted up instead of below the action bar. Also - Do people normally format preferences, or should it automatically know to be displayed under the action bar? I am thinking my issue might be somewhere else if this is the case.

Comment: it should be working fine. this is not normal behavior. are you working with appcompat and the toolbar?

Comment: yeah, I am working with appcompat...is that the reason? If so, any ideas to work around it?

Comment: if you're working with appcompat, then you should be using a toolbar. or caling setSupportActionBar somewhere. Perhaps that's related? I'm really not sure at this point.